# Defining formats for text in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a web page and have been banging my head over this for the last hour with no luck.

I'm writing a few paragraphs and want it to follow two constraints:

1) The div that it resides in needs to be centered, but I don't want the actual text inside the div to be centered. An example would be the links/text here: http://paulstamatiou.com/

2) I want to constrain the text to the size of the div, and when a line meets that boundary, it breaks the line wherever it is and simply continues with left alignment on the next line. When I shrink the window, I don't want to hide any of the overflow.

My `<pre>` tags have the class preformatted, which I've customized as

```
.preformatted {

    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;


}
```

Sorry for the noobish question, I've tried to find my solution elsewhere. I've been messing with the overflow, whitespace, and some other tags to no luck. There has to be an easier way to do this than individually spacing each line like I'm doing right now.

Comment: you should create a jsfiddle of your code so that we can debug it, you didn't really give us enough to work with in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but you can center a div with `margin: 0 auto` without affecting the alignment of the text it contains.  Each line of the text will break to a new line once it reaches the width of the `div`.  Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vx9K9/

Answer (score 0):

1) There are couple of ways to center your div. One and old method is `margin: 0 auto;`. Also you can try `position` or `margin` which satisfy your needs.

2) If you want to wrap your text up when it exceeds the border of div, you need to use `overflow:hidden;` on your div object.

Comment: You'll also need to have a width or max-width on the element to make the margin trick work.